# How to not sum if association is not present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the error `undefined method 'amount' for nil:NilClass` if the Tax (`tax_id`) is not present on any products.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :tax_id
  belongs_to :tax

  def self.total_with_tax
    self.sum(:amount) + all.map(&:tax).map(&:amount).sum
  end
end

class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount
  has_many :products
end
```

Is there a way I can make it so if there's no Tax ID present when it searches all of the products, it will render it as nil and just do `self.sum(:amount)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you could scope the products to only map those that actually have a `tax_id`. Something like:

```
self.sum(:amount) + self.where("tax_id IS NOT NULL").map(&:tax).map(&:amount).sum
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a [`compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) after the `all.map(&:tax)` then, it will be an empty array, which will not get into the `map(&:amount)` so no error and then the sum of it would be 0.

```
self.sum(:amount) + all.map(&:tax).compact.map(&:amount).sum

>> [nil].map(&:amount).sum
# NoMethodError: undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass
>> [nil].compact.map(&:amount).sum
#=> 0
```